# Assembly Language:Can physical address be 16 bits in segmented memory model?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on a University assignment of Assembly language related to memory addressing.Can physical address be 16 bits? Following are the values provided by instructor.

```
BX=0x0000
SI=0x01A2
DS=0x0A2E

Effective Address:
EA = Base + Index + Offset
    = 0x0000+0x01A2+0xFF00
    =0x100A2
    = 0x00A2

Physical:
=Segment * 10 + EA
=0x0A2E * 10 + 0x00A2
= 0xA382 (16 bits)
```

Is it correct because physical memory address has to be 20 bits long.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about [tag:x86] assembly? There's more than one architecture around.

Comment: The 16-bit 8086 processor has 20 discrete address pins and so directly addresses a 20-bit address. The address is composed of the segment and offset. The offset is 16 bits. So in your example, the total *offset*, which is `base + index + offset` is `0x00A2` as you show. It would be clearer if you showed this in the context of an x86 instruction, since it's unclear where `Offset` comes from in your example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Assignment is with reference to IAPX8088

Comment: IAPX8088 is x86 architecture

Comment: @lurker Instructor asked to calculate Physical Address based on register values supplied. I was not expecting Physical Address to be 16 Bits. I am a learner so I don't know if 16 bits PA is logically correct but experienced programmer can comment if it is logically okay. If it is not logically ok then Instructor might have supplied wrong values.

Comment: @lurker Please bear with me as I am a beginner here.I am not sure what you mean by instruction example.This is all what he supplied to calculate physical address.

Comment: In an 8088 or 8086 type processor (the IAPX8088 is 8088 type), the physical address is 20 bits. It is determined by a *segment* and an *offset*, each of which is 16 bits. The 20 bit address is computed by `segment * 0x10 + offset`. What you are calling `EA` is a total *offset*, and is 16 bits. The Physical Address calculation you are showing is the correct value, but technically it will be 20 bits: `0x0A382`.

Comment: @lurker Thank You. I learned alot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Leading Zeros**

A physical address in a x86 processor in 16-bit-mode is in fact 20 bit long. In your example the leading zeros have been cut away.

```
0x0A2E * 0x10   = 0x0A2E0
       + 0x00A2 = 0x0A382 
                = 0xA382
```

So the address 0A2E:00A2 points to the same memory cell as 0000:A382.